# Running a long-running Task within a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I have written a Windows Service project which hosts a long-running message pump task which is meant to run for the duration of the service. When the service starts, it starts the task. When the service stops, it stops the task:

```
void OnStart()
{
    MessagePump.Start();
}

void OnStop()
{
    MessagePump.Stop();
}
```

Where MessagePump.Start does a Task.Factory.StartNew, and MessagePump.Stop signals the task to stop and does a Wait().

So far so good, but I'm wondering how best to handle faults. If the task has an unhandled exception, I'd want the service to stop but since nothing is typically Wait-ing on the task, I imagine it'll just sit doing nothing. How can I elegantly handle this situation?

UPDATE:

The consensus seems to be using 'await' or ContinueWith. Here is how I'm currently coding my Start method to use this:

```
public async static void Start()
{
    this.state = MessagePumpState.Running;
    this.task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.ProcessLoop(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    try
    {
        await this.task;
    }
    catch
    {
        this.state = MessagePumpState.Faulted;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use async/await with cancellation Options. When you will have unhandled exception, make cancellation and you program will know about error

Comment: Can I do that within a Windows Service? My understanding is that if I do an await within OnStart() then it'll not exit until the task completes? (could be wrong)

Comment: Hmm. What about not awaiting Task on MessagePump.Start()? Check this blog, may be you will find what you are looking for. http://blog.stephencleary.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make you MessagePump.Start() method return the task. Then

```
MessagePump.Start().ContinueWith(t => 
{
    // handle exception 
}, 
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

UPDATE:
I would do the next:

```
private MessagePump _messagePump;

async void OnStart()
{
    this._messagePump = new MessagePump();
    try
    {
        // make Start method return the task to be able to handle bubbling exception here
        await _messagePump.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log exception
        // abort service
    }
}

void OnStop()
{
    _messagePump.Stop();
}

public enum MessagePumpState
{
    Running,
    Faulted
}

public class MessagePump
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancallationTokenSrc;
    private MessagePumpState _state;
    public async Task Start()
    {
        if (_cancallationTokenSrc != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Task is already running!");
        }

        this._state = MessagePumpState.Running;
        _cancallationTokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.ProcessLoop(_cancallationTokenSrc.Token), _cancallationTokenSrc.Token);
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch
        {
            this._state = MessagePumpState.Faulted;
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_cancallationTokenSrc != null)
        {
            _cancallationTokenSrc.Cancel();
            _cancallationTokenSrc = null;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessLoop(CancellationToken token)
    {
        // check if task has been canceled
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably if I used await, the code execution would presumably sit there waiting for the task to end without exiting OnStart?

Comment: @Barguast wrap this logic in an async method, use await there, and discard the task that this async method returns. That way you don't have to deal with nasty continuations and the program continues.

Comment: @Barguast no, await doesn't block your calling thread. It's just the same (almost) as ContinueWith.

Comment: @sedovav - Thanks, this is helpful. I've updated my first post with an example of what my Start method now looks like. It uses await and an exception handler (only to set a member field) and seems to be working how I expected. It is an 'async void' though which seems a bit odd, but makes more sense that returning a Task (and avoids a compiler warning). If it isn't too much to ask, could you give it a glance to see if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Barguast wrap the code in an async Task and discard the resulting task. Add a code comment. Async void interacts with the sync context in a way you probably don't want (or understand).

Comment: @Barguast you should avoid async void methods. Look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: If I change it to 'async Task', the faults go ignored again (because, again, I've got a task that no-one is waiting on). I think the best approach might be to use await (within Start) and wrap it in a try / catch. In my catch, invoke an event (like with Sasha's answer) and handle the stopping of my service in an event handler? Then I shouldn't need to worry about relying on an unhandled exception to close my service (which seems preferable)

Comment: @sedovav mostly we should avoid async void methods, but in this case is ok. Like for Events - fire and Forget. Here it's the same - no need to wait a result of this method.

Comment: Thanks. I can't say I'm totally sure of the reasons why a void return is problematic in this particular circumstance, but your latest edit looks very helpful. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
void OnStart()
{
    MessagePump.StartAsync(); 
    MessagePump.ErrorEvent += OnError();
}
```

Then your StartAsync will look something like:

```
public async Task StartAsync()
{
     // your process
     // if error, send event to messagePump
}
```

And if you decide to use Tasks, then it is better to use Task.Run and not Task.Factory.StartNew()

Comment: Thanks. I added a 'Faulted' event to my class, which seems to be how things like ServiceHost handle this. Your last sentence was interesting too - I thought Task.Run was basically the same as Task.Factory.StartNew but minus some of the complex options. I think I should be setting LongRunning on my task at least. Not sure if there are any other benefits to Task.Run?

Comment: @Barguast have a look at this artcile http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx